# CakePHP invalid data format on saveAll() using input helper

Tags: cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP(2.2.3) for the first time, and I'm having this issue.
I created a simple form with the Input helper in order to try the `saveAll()` method.

Here's the form code. No big deal.

```
$this->Form->create('Section');
$this->Form->input("Section.0.title");
$this->Form->input("Section.1.title");
$this->Form->end('Save');
```

According to CakePHP's docs, in order to do a `saveAll()`, you need an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Section] => Array
                (
                    [title] => title 1
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Section] => Array
                (
                    [title] => title 2
                )

        )

)
```

However, if I dump `$this->request->data`, the array I get from the form is like this:

```
Array
(
    [Section] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => title 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => title 2
                )
        )
)
```

I guess that when using the Input helper in such a simple situation, `$this->request->data` array should have the valid format. So I guess I'm missing something, but I can't find what.

Is there a way to get the array in the valid format, or do I need to create a custom method to rewrite it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what are your model associations

Comment: Hi Colby Guyer. I don't have any, yet. But if I rewrite the `$this->request->data` array in the controller following the valid format above (you know, just to see what happens), everything works. So I guess it has nothing to do with model associations. Thank you for answering ;-)

Comment: Have you tried actually saving it ye?  My guess is your format is fine.

Comment: Hi Dave. Yes, I have tried, but data can't be validated. As I said to Colby Guyer (comment above), if I pass a valid array format (as says in the docs) it just works. The case is: why the Form helper gives an invalid array format? Thank you for joining.

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda - you have yet to mention anything about validation.

Comment: Hi @Dave Maybe I'm not being clear enough. The thing is: using the Form helper as in the example above, I get an array with this structure -> `data[Model][key][field]`. However, in order to make a `saveAll()`, you need this structure -> `data[key][Model][field]`. So my question is: am I doing something wrong, or this is the normal behaviour and I should just rewrite the array with a custom method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to save multiple records of a single model, the array should be numerical indexed, so `$this->Section->saveAll($this->request->data['Section']);` will do it for you

Comment: Thank you @Ceeram ! That solved my issue. Oh boy, I don't know how I hadn't thought of this... So simple! ;-)